# Attaching Multiple files to Outlook Email in a loop

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, outlook, email-attachments

I am trying to draw editable inputs from cells in the active spreadsheet. I managed to generate an email in Outlook and attach multiple files.

The problem is instead of cycling through each cell with data (and different directory inputs) thereby attaching "x" amount of individual files, it attaches the same file "x" times.

```
Option Explicit

Sub TESTCreateEmail()


    'define variables for outlook
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem

    'define variables for attachements to email
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LoopAttach As Integer
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer

    x = Range("E9", Range("E100").End(xlUp)).Count

    'set parameters for outlook
    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    'set parameters for attachements to email
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Application.ActiveSheet

    'create email
    With olMail

        .To = ws.Range("H9")
        .CC = ws.Range("I9")
        olMail.SentOnBehalfOfName = "email@email.com"
        olMail.Recipients.ResolveAll
        .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML

        olMail.HTMLBody = "<html><p><font face=""Calibri""><font size=3>Dear Sir/ Madam,</p>"

        'loop to attach multiple files
        For LoopAttach = 1 To x
            .Attachments.Add ws.Range("E9").Offset(x - 1, 0) _
            & ws.Range("F9").Offset(x - 1, 0)
        Next LoopAttach

       .Display

    End With

End Sub
```

[image: Examples of Excel input and resulting Outlook email]

Answer (score 0):

In your code variable x value remains same during executing the loop. That’s why its attaching the same file every time when loop gets executed.

Try this

```
    For LoopAttach = x To 1 Step -1
        .Attachments.Add ws.Range("E9").Offset(LoopAttach - 1, 0) _
        & ws.Range("F9").Offset(LoopAttach - 1, 0)
    Next LoopAttach
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simple mistake - x is constant limit of for loop. You need to use `LoopAttach` variable instead of `x`.

```
For LoopAttach = 1 To x
    .Attachments.Add ws.Range("E9").Offset(LoopAttach - 1, 0) _
    & ws.Range("F9").Offset(LoopAttach - 1, 0)
Next LoopAttach
```